# Split an integral in a multidimensional space, is this correct?

Tags: integration

Let $n\geq 2$, $X=[0,1]^n$ and $\theta\subset Y$ an open subset of $Y$. For a function $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, is the following equality correct?
$$\int_X f(\boldsymbol{x}) \mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{x} = \int_{X\setminus\overline{\theta}} f(\boldsymbol{x})\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{x} + \int_{\theta} f(\boldsymbol{x})\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{x} $$
I am having doubts whether or not this holds for any dimension $n$. What I am missing, is that the integral over the boundary $\partial\theta$ seems to be missing to me, especially when considering $n\geq 2$. Can I simply split the integral in this way?

Comment: It is no accident the boundary is missing, this happened because it is integrated in both directions, which will always cancel out. You can think of each intergral on the right-hand side as summing up an *oriented* area. Since these orientations are the same (our space is orientable; why?) you will integrate boundary once in a given direction, then again, in the opposite direction.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I am able to imagine how in terms of oriented areas it is possible to drop the boundary integral. Does it matter whether I am considering $\theta$ and $X\setminus\overline{\theta}$ or can I also write on the right hand side the same with $\theta$ and $X\setminus\theta$? Intuitively I would think this to be possible, since the boundary $\partial\theta$ is a set with Lebesgue measure $0$.

Comment: You could write it instead with both terms involving the boundary, but don't write only 1 of them that way! Both or none. (Otherwise you'd be counting the boundary only once, in one of the possible directions and may get a non-vanishing boundary contribution, which is different from the given scenario).

Comment: I understand. Thank you a lot, you have helped me getting clarity concerning this knot I had in my head!